# What are all built-in abstract classes in .net framework?

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class, built-in

I have been searching but unable to find a proper list. Can someone please name a few or gimme some link regarding that?

Comment: Because I am curious to know. That's why :/ Why am I getting down vote ? :(

Comment: There is no such consolidated list, whatsoever! MSDN gives you details per class, but there is no mechanism in there to list only abstract classes or based on category. VS gives you hints/doesn't allows you to instantiate such classes. And, I don't know why you got down-votes! Although, you may write a small program based on reflection to list such classes!

Comment: The OP is not asking for every abstract class in .Net FW. He might be looking for practical uses of abstract classes and what can be more authoritative than the FW itself? Even a tiny list could have lead him in right direction instead of downvoting.

Comment: Controller class in MVC , Stream class in IO.stream name space etc are examples for built in abstract class in .net

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This (quick and dirty) program should give you a list to get started with from 4.0;

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var assemblies = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework" + (Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "64" : "") + "\\v4.0.30319", "*.dll");

        foreach(var assembly in assemblies)
        {
            try
            {
                var loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly);
                var types = loadedAssembly.GetTypes();
                foreach(var type in types)
                    if(type.IsAbstract && type.IsClass)
                        Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Not an assembly? Ignore.
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for writing a program, I was still thinking of!